# How do I install `timgm6mb-soundfont`?

Tags: linux, debian, linux-mint, software-installation, package-management

I'm trying to install the `timgm6mb-soundfont` package on Linux Mint 17. 3 (Rosa). However, `sudo apt-get install timgm6mb-soundfont` keeps failing with an `unable to locate package` error.

I installed `apt-file` and tried to find the package, but that didn't work. All my package lists are updated, and I'm under the impression that I should be able to install `timgm6mb-soundfont` using `apt-get`.

I found the [package on debian](https://packages.debian.org/source/sid/timgm6mb-soundfont) but don't know how to install it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem just now: for some reason, my `etc/apt/sources.list` file did not contain all the necessary repositories. I added the line:

`deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily main universe`

and then was able to find and install the package with `apt-get`.

Comment: I will be accepting my own answer in 2 days unless a better one comes in!

Comment: `wily` has to be replaced with the matching Ubuntu version for your distro (`wily` itself is dead already). `us` should be replaced with your local mirror as in other `sources.list` items.